# Cpanel user DB config

Tags: mysql

Where does cPanel/WHM store its associations between users and their MySQL databases? I can't seem to find anything in /home/$USER, or /var/cpanel, or /etc/..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newer cPanel versions, cPanel stores this config in /var/cpanel/databases/username.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I was unfortunate enough to use cPanel, it just looked for any databases that matched `/^<USERNAME>_.*$/`

Answer (score 0):

In the mysql database, there is a table called "db".  In this table, it shows which users have which accesses to which DBs.  This is most probably where WHM stores the actual ACLs that allow user1 access to his DB, and his DB only.

Or, are you asking where it stores the properties of "which DBs to show in the control panel for this user"?  If so, that may be best posed to the CPanel user list.  I think that is in the CPanel database somewhere.

Comment: The "db" table in the "mysql" database is used by MySQL to determine which mysql users have access to which databases. Im interested in knowing how cPanel determines which databases are "owned" by a given cpanel user. For example, when you create a backup for a user, cPanel will include in the backup the databases that the user "owns". How does it know which ones?

Comment: It keeps its own set of files to handle which users own which databases.  It is in the CPanel code itself, and located in the CPanel system directories somewhere.

Your best bet would be to ask a CPanel specialist on their user boards or something.  I don't have enough experience to guess well.